# Implementing a multi-columned array sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort data in an array that looks like this:

```
(String, int, String, double)
```

or

```
(David, 25, Da, 123.54)
```

I want the delineation for the array sort to be decided by the "integer" value. So, for example:

```
David, 25, Da, 123.54
Sean, 27, Pa, 514.21
Luke, 32, Ma, 221.54
```

These values are being read from a file, organized in a constructor,and sent back to the driver.

Here's what I have so far, I'm not sure of how much use it will be:

```
    public class NamesAges{
       public String[] display() throws IOException {  

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("elements.csv");  

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);  
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();  
    String line = null;  

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)  
    {  
        lines.add(line);  
        System.out.println(line);
    }  

    bufferedReader.close();  

    String[] sl = (String[]) lines.toArray(new String[0]);


    return sl;
    }  
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: *"I want the delineation for the array sort to be decided by the "integer" value."*  O..K.  Given there is exactly one column that has an integer value, how is this a 'multi-column' sort?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend encapsulating each row into an `Object` and writing a `Comparator` to sort them as needed.  Java's an object-oriented language; stop thinking in terms of primitives and Strings.

Comment: but `String`s aren't primitives.

Comment: They are the way you're using them.

Comment: True. Your wording is a bit confusing, though.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be to create a class that encapsulates the four values, make the class implement `Comparable` and define its `compareTo()` method via the integer.